# Transform-origin problem while resizing div in an animation

Tags: html, css

While trying to make a small css animation I encountered a small problem with the transform-origin property of css.
To illustrate what I'm talking about I designed what I wanted with a cms here's what I want to get but using a cms the code is more complicated:

```
.main {
margin:30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgb(230, 60, 60);
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 68px;
  height: 25px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate3d(-8.93274px, -0.0896834px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 33.9995px 12.5px 0px;
}
@keyframes gwd-gen-1wa0gwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% {
    width: 68px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 33.9995px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-8.93274px, -0.0896834px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.415, 0.189, 0, 1.079);
  }
  14.2857% {
    width: 185px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 33.9995px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-8.93274px, -0.0896834px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  28.5714% {
    width: 185px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 33.9995px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-8.93274px, -0.0896834px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.255, 0.269, 0.445, 0.879);
  }
  42.8571% {
    width: 68px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 12.4211px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(108px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  57.1429% {
    width: 68px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 12.5035px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(108px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.415, 0.189, 0, 1.079);
  }
  71.4286% {
    width: 185px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 34.0926px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-9px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  85.7143% {
    width: 185px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 34.0926px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-9px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease;
  }
  100% {
    width: 68px;
    height: 25px;
    transform-origin: 12.5583px 12.5px 0px;
    transform: translate3d(-9px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
}
.main {
  animation: gwd-gen-1wa0gwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 1.2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running;
}
```

I tried to reproduce it without using 3d properties as when using the cms but my problem is that when the div resizes it moves at its ends and then changes orientation when it should behave like with the css. So here's what I got by doing just the first part of the animation (where my div grows from the right and shrinks on the left side) But it moves during the resizing:

```css
    .main{
    animation: resize 2s ease  1 normal forwards;
    height:30px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    transform-origin:left;
    margin-left:100px;
    }
    @keyframes resize {
    0%{
    
    }
    50%{ 
    transform-origin:left;
    transform:scalex(2);
    }
    100%
    {
    transform-origin:right;
    transform:scalex(0.8);
    }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the scale is not correct! You should combine the position and the scale. Since the scale does not change the actual position. Similarly, to your 3D animation, you should also combine several animations together. Here is my solution.

```css
.main{
        animation: resize 2s ease  1 normal forwards;
        height:30px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:red;
        transform-origin:left;
        margin-left:100px;
      }
      @keyframes resize {
        0%{

        }
        50%{
          transform-origin:left;
          transform:scalex(2) ;
        }
        100%{
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```